# got error "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out" in intellij

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm getting an error in IntelliJ IDEA when im using a thin connection from java to oracle.

My oracle database is in a server and I can ping the server but my code can't establish connection:

```
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server ip:1521:orcl","user","path");
        System.out.println("Oracle Registered...");
```

and error is:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out
```

Comment: IntelliJ has nothing to do with this.  It's just an IDE.  I'll assume that you have something sensible in your URL to substitute for "server ip".  That needs to be a URL or XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX IP address that your client can see.

Comment: @duffymo you are right. I deleted the tag

Comment: Is the server's firewall configured correctly?  A quick Google search provides this page as a list of ports for Oracle products.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15660/app_port.htm

Comment: firewall is ok.i can ping server.server ip is 172:1:16:64 and i write @172:1:16:64 for server ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the network is reachable but the operations take too much time.

Check if you can establish a connection using a standard db client like toad, sql server or squirrel.

If you can use the same paramters in java and it should work.

If you can't check if another process is using port 1521 on the server.

Comment: i have checked and port is free.how can i stablish standard connection?